# does returning a vector in c++ append?

Tags: c++, vector

I am working with vectors in C++ and I came up with the following MWE that I don't quite understand:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<double> pb()
{
    vector<double> a;
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> asd;
    asd = pb();
    cout << asd.size() << endl;

    asd = pb();
    cout << asd.size() << endl; //WHY DOES THIS GIVE 3, AND NOT 6? asd HAS NOT BEEN EMPTIED AT ANY POINT


    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why my vector `asd` is "initialized" everytime I call `pb()`. What I would expect was that calling `pb()` would merely append to the contents of `asd`.

Comment: why are you expecting that? do you expect that `a = 3` adds 3 to `a`?

Comment: The cause of the vector being "initialized" (not the technical term), is not the call to `pb`.  It is the call to `operator=` with `asd` as the left operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `pb` you create a new vector and pushes three items into it, and then return it. It's then copied to `asb` in your `main` function and removes the old content.

How would the function `pb` know that it should append to the vector? It doesn't. You have to pass it to the function instead.

```
void pb(std::vector<double>& a)
{
    // Push back items...
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> asd;

    pb(asd);

    // ...
}
```

As you can see I changed the function to *not* return the vector. Instead it's passed as a *reference* argument.

Answer (score 2):

It's not "initialized" every time; it's reassigned with the result of the function call, which contains 3 items. The old contents are destroyed when it's reassigned.

If you want to append, use the `append` member function rather than reassigning. Alternatively, pass a reference to the function and append to that, rather than to a new vector.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, this should give you the answer you want:

```
vector<double> pb(vector<double> &a)
{
    a.push_back(1);
    a.push_back(2);
    a.push_back(3);
}

int main()
{
    vector<double> asd;
    pb( asd );
    cout << asd.size() << endl;

    pb( asd );
    cout << asd.size() << endl; //WHY DOES THIS GIVE 3, AND NOT 6? asd HAS NOT BEEN EMPTIED AT ANY POINT

    return 0;
}
```

**Longer story:**
Each time you call `pb()` in the original version of code presented, you *created a new* `std::vector` and then push to that new `vector`. After `pb()` returns, the `asd` is *assigned* to the newly created & filled `vector`, instead of being appended to.

Comment: You say that `pb` returns a vector, but it has no `return` statement.